# Dynamic database connection connection not updating until RoR is restarted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The variable used by establish_connection is changing, but for some reason the model doesn't switch to the updated configuration until Rails is restarted. How can I get the model to dynamically connect to a different database successfully?

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
 establish_connection(ExtDBInfo.current_ext_db)
end
```

Comment: Rails does not update the connection, because the above configuration is set only once when the class is loaded. You might want to add a class method that triggers a re-configuration. Why do you want to do that? What do you try to achieve? Is a load balancer in front of the database an option?

Comment: yeah thats what I figured, I tried a before_validation but that didn't work. could you post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to a new connection dynamically using this snippet:

```
connection_info = Submission.configurations[RAILS_ENV].clone
connection_info['database'] = 'new_database'
Submission.establish_connection(connection_info)
```

In first line we get existing settings for connection (`clone` is essential). Then we update settings to desired (in this case only `database` is updated) and then reestablishing the connection.

If you need to return to default configuration, you can use:

```
Submission.establish_connection(RAILS_ENV)
```

See more info http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class